# C++ undefined reference linker error with inherited template virtual function and complicated usage

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I have a somewhat complicated class hierarchy where the topmost class declares a function to be virtual, and some of the derived classes in the chain override the virtual function. The actual structure is something like:

```
class A {
 public:
    virtual void Reset() = 0;
    
    void NextBlock() {
        [...]
        Reset();
    }
};

class B: public A {
 public:
    void Reset() override {
    ...
    }
};

template <typename T>
class C: public B {
 public:
    void Reset() override {
    ...
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
class D: public C<T> {
 public:
    void Reset() override {
    ...
    }
};

class E1 final: public D<Foo1, Bar1> {
 public:
    // Does not override Reset
    void functionality1();
    void functionality2();
};

class E2 final: public D<Foo2, Bar2> {
 public:
    // Does not override Reset
    void functionality1();
    void functionality2();
};

class E3 final: public D<Foo3, Bar3> {
 public:
    // Does not override Reset
    void functionality1();
    void functionality2();
};

...
```

In each override the definition is included inline with the declaration, and this chain is defined in a header file. I have multiple final classes that inherit from the pentultimate class, as represented here with multiple `E` classes.

I then have several .cpp files that implement the main functionality of the classes - here I represent this with `functionality1` and `functionality2` as the implementations can be split across two files.

On compilation, I get a linker error like `undefined reference to 'D<Foo2, Bar2>::Reset()'`. It only triggers for one of the `E` classes (say `E2`), even though the inheritance structure is the same for all the `E` classes and all the `E::functionality()` implementations had called `A::NextBlock()`, which in turns calls `D::Reset()`. I'm very puzzled as to why this happens and was wondering if anyone here has a clue.

In my case, only one of the functionalities caused the linker error. In the example, it's like if I removed `E2::functionality2` there'd suddenly be no more linker errors. The `E` classes being `final` also mattered, as the linker error also disappears if I remove the `final` keyword for the problem class.

When looking up online for the undefined reference linker problem, I typically see advice about having the function definitions visible to all translation units, as this linker error also occurs if the class definition is not in the header file. In my case I inlined all my functions and the .cpp file can see the definitions, so that wasn't the problem.

I also tried to reproduce the error with a smaller example, but I couldn't. One attempt is on https://godbolt.org/z/crdhzccPv. I cannot share my full-sized code that does hit the linker error - it is proprietary.

I was able to work around the problem by changing the definition of the problem class kind of like:

```
class E2 final: public D<Foo2, Bar2> {
 public:
    void Reset();
    void functionality1();
    void functionality2();
};
```

And then including a stub like the following in a .cpp file:

```
void E2::Reset() {
  D<Foo2, Bar2>::Reset();
}
```

At this point I'm suspecting this is a compiler bug. My implementation for the problem functionality of the problem class may generate a fair amount of code. It also is highly abstracted and heavily uses template classes internal to the .cpp file. I'm thinking that the compiler decides not to inline the call to `Reset`, but my program enters a weird branch of the compiler so it doesn't actually create a symbol for the function. In my attempts to repro this problem with less code I notice that the `final` keyword triggers devirtualization optimizations, but that the existence of template base classes can cause devirtualization to fail even if the template parameters are explicitly provided at the most derived class. It's possible that I'm triggering edge cases in the compiler when it tries to devirtualize the calls to `Reset` while trying to handle templated base classes. In the end I'm not sure though, maybe there's much a simpler explanation here?

Comment: *At this point I'm suspecting this is a compiler bug*
Usually I get to this point about 5 minutes before I find the facepalm mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Is any occurrence of `Reset` implemented in a source file rather than a header file ?

Comment: No, the declaration and all the overrides for Reset appear inside the header file